# Project name mismatch using FeedbackReporter

Tags: php, objective-c, cocoa, feedback, user-feedback

I'm using FeedbackReporter by http://vafer.org/tcurdt, and everything works *except* when I submit, it says

`Error submitting your feedback to the server.
Error: project name mismatch.`

Here is the output:

`2014-07-14 12:28:40.422 MyApp[4422:bd3b] Found 0 crash files
2014-07-14 12:28:40.422 MyApp[4422:bd3b] Script exit code = -1
2014-07-14 12:28:59.217 MyApp[4422:303] Sending feedback to http://myurl.com/MyApp/Feedback/submit.php?project=MyApp
2014-07-14 12:28:59.218 MyApp[4422:303] Posting 29197 bytes to http://myurl.com.com/MyApp/Feedback/submit.php?project=MyApp
2014-07-14 12:29:03.054 MyApp[4422:303] Connection received data
2014-07-14 12:29:03.058 MyApp[4422:303] Failed to submit to server: ERR 007
project name mismatch
2014-07-14 12:32:25.691 MyApp[4422:303] Sending feedback to http://myurl.com/MyApp/Feedback/submit.php?project=MyApp
2014-07-14 12:32:25.692 MyApp[4422:303] Posting 29197 bytes to http://myurl.com/MyApp/Feedback/submit.php?project=MyApp
2014-07-14 12:32:28.175 MyApp[4422:303] Connection received data
2014-07-14 12:32:28.179 MyApp[4422:303] Failed to submit to server: ERR 007
project name mismatch`

Please help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.
In your Info.plist file, you set the key of 'FRFeedbackReporter.targetURL' to: http://myurl.com.com/MyApp/Feedback/submit.php?filename=%@, where filename is the name of the file the feedback will be stored in. Then in the config.php file you set the path of the folder that you want the reports to be in as well.